# TSQL include data even if null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is looking for data in my table called `csScheduleAgents`. When you hit the page for the first time, it grabs your userID and checks that table for information. It is joining the employee table with all of the records.

The issue I am running into is that if `A.[empID]` doesnt exist, it fails to get the data from `B.[]`; so the join fails.

How can I make this statement work even if there is no record for `A.[empID]` as its still being passed as a variable.

```
SELECT A.[id],
   A.[empID],
   A.[shiftPref],
   CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), A.[lastUpdated], 101) AS lastUpdated,
   B.[firstName],
   B.[lastName],
   B.[SupEmpID],
   B.[DepartmentDesc] + ' ' + B.[SkillSetDesc] as SkillSetDesc,
   C.[firstName] + ' ' + C.[lastName] AS supervisor
 FROM   csScheduleAgents AS A
   INNER JOIN
   empTable AS B
   ON B.[empID] = A.[empID]
   INNER JOIN
   empTable AS C
   ON C.[empID] = B.[SupEmpID]
 WHERE  A.[empID] = @empID
 FOR    XML PATH ('details'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
END
```

Comment: What data do you want returned if A.empID does not exist?

Comment: The data exists in the employee table (empTable) regardless. Its just because A.[empID] doenst exist, it doesnt even fetch the data from the empTable like im wanting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, and also set the `WHERE` clause to filter your records using the `[empID]` from the `empTable` table.

```
    SELECT A.[id],
           A.[empID],
           A.[shiftPref],
           CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), A.[lastUpdated], 101) AS lastUpdated,
           B.[firstName],
           B.[lastName],
           B.[SupEmpID],
           B.[DepartmentDesc] + ' ' + B.[SkillSetDesc] as SkillSetDesc,
           C.[firstName] + ' ' + C.[lastName] AS supervisor
    FROM   csScheduleAgents AS A
           RIGHT JOIN
           empTable AS B
           ON B.[empID] = A.[empID]
           RIGHT JOIN
           empTable AS C
           ON C.[empID] = B.[SupEmpID]
    WHERE  B.[empID] = @empID
    FOR    XML PATH ('details'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
END
```

This will return ALL records from the right side, even when the left side is `NULL`.

Comment: I tried this but it returned NULL on the data when A.[empID] was not found in csScheduleAgents

Comment: I'm confused then.  Isn't that what you want?  You said "How can I make this statement work even if there is no record for A.[empID]..."

Comment: @SBB - Ummm, yeah...  If you have `WHERE a.[empID] = @empID` but no records match, then you get no results...  Try filtering on the employee table instead, where I presume that employee *must* exist?  `WHERE b.[empID] = @empID`.

Comment: So I have 2 tables. EmpTable and csScheduleAgents. My script passed @empID to this stored procedure. If its the first time the agent is using this script, there is going to be no records found in csScheduleAgents so I just want to pull their information from the empTable. But whats happening is because that record doesnt exist , it wont even get the information from empTable that actually does exist.

Comment: @SBB - Then your `WHERE` clause needs to filter on the table where the record Does exist, not the one where it might not.  See my comment above...

Comment: @SBB -- Try again with my updated query.  I took into account what MatBailie is saying.

Comment: @roryap - Even better, I'd lay the query out as `employee LEFT JOIN super LEFT JOIN schedule`  The OPs query feels a bit inside out.

Comment: @MatBailie -- I agree, but I didn't want to go that far and completely rearrange his query.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want a [RIGHT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp) for that.

> The RIGHT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the right table (table2),
>   with the matching rows in the left table (table1). The result is NULL
>   in the left side when there is no match.